# How can i develop a Facebook app for Pages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I'm trying to develop a facebook app for facebook pages (Ex: the page has a tab that opens the app directly in the facebook interface).
Unfortunatly i'm not finding any documentation about... I found docs for classical facebook apps, (Ex: a website that want to load some data from facebook).

I don't understand how this kind of apps work.. Are the apps only iframes that show one of my server php? how can I define this relation?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs

Comment: So, this way, I specify one of my server's php?

Comment: You provide a URL, that then gets loaded into an iframe on the page tab.